Что такое родительский экземпляр класса и текущий экземпляр класса?
Что такое родительский экземпляр класса и текущий экземпляр класса?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Явно дубликат вопроса Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#

@АлексейШиманский а можно конкретный ответ?

@saidrajabov конечно: открой книгу для новичков и почитай основы языка, которые в любой из миллиарда книг для новичков написаны

да пока я искать буду, уж лучше мне кто-нибудь ответит.

Я сомневаюсь, что где-то можно найти объяснение значения словосочетания "родительский экземпляр класса". Так что предлагаю экспертам высказаться.

"родительский экземпляр класса" - это что-то странное всё-таки )  "родительский класс" - понятно, "экземпляр класса" - понятно, даже "экземпляр родительского класса" - и то понятно, но вот "родительский экземпляр класса" - непонятно

Что такое родительский экземпляр класса ... => приведите, пожалуйста источник, где указана такая формулировка

@Dev18 так это учебные тесты. Преподы какиенть  составляли.

@rotabor, к тестам есть методички, в которых должны быть указаны все термины. Если их нет, то ответить на такой тест невозможно ¯\(ツ)/¯

@rotabor да не тест это никакой, сам так сформулировал. просто плохо разобрался и сразу побежал спрашивать. крч надо было внимательнее слушать.

А мы тут голову ломаем!

Текущий экземпляр:
public class Person
{
    private string _name = "";
 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}

Родительский экземпляр (через наследование):
class Employee : Person
{
     
}

Для класса Employee базовым является Person, и поэтому класс Employee наследует все те же свойства, методы, поля, которые есть в классе Person. источник кода, и более развернутое объяснение

Простыми словами:
Родительский экземпляр класса — это "встроенная" часть объекта, которая "унаследована" от родительского класса. В каждом Employee есть "часть" Person, от которого он наследуется. Поэтому Employee может использовать свойства и методы Person, как будто они "встроены" в него.
На мой взгляд выражение "родительский экземпляр" как отдельный объект отсутствует(?) — доступны его члены (свойства, методы, поля) внутри производного класса

Не отвечает на вопрос, и нет в ответе логики. Например, упомянут this, но в коде его нет.  И "родительский экземпляр класса" меня интересует больше всего.

@rotabor, так пойдет?

Ну, Саиду подошло. А как получить "родительский экземпляр класса"?

В коде для "Родительский экземпляр (через наследование)" приведено объявление класса - наследника Person. Где там родительский экземпляр?

@rotabor, я не нашла дубликатов. Но, у меня вопрос, когда вы говорите экземпляр - это же подразумевает new()(?), но это невозможно в данном примере (?)

Экземпляр - это employee Employee employee = new Employee(). Родительский экземпляр - возможно это person Person person = new Employee(). Возможно, "текущий экземпляр" как-то связан с ключевым словом this, которое применяется в граниченном числе случаев, когда нужно: явно указать экземпляр объекта для различения его членов от локальных переменных; для доступа в методе расширения; для определения индексатора.

я говорила о ~Employee = new Person();~=> такое невозможно //может вы ответите?

Employee employee = new Person() - нет, так не получится.

Наверное, этот ответ лучше удалить.

@rotabor, https://i.sstatic.net/zxGKEM5n.png //я постоянно обдумываю разные темы, если один день найду, пойму улучшения изменю, а так...на скрин шоте видно, что я не могу удалить этот ответ//Может еще и ТС перефоормулирует вопрос

Ах, он же принятый. Всё равно +11 осталось.

@rotabor, Вы о минусах?  я же знаю кто поставил, и знаю зачем. Нет ничего криминального. Наоборот надо прокручивать тему, чтоб тоньше понимать

Если кратко, такого термина как "родительский экземпляр", попросту не существует. Есть просто экземпляр класса. Такие термины появляются в голове молодого разработчика в результате перепутывания понятий класса и объекта.
